# What is the default unit of style in React Native?

Tags: android, css, reactjs, material-design, react-native

I am contributing to an Open Source Project where I am developing Material design for React Native. I am blocked at work,I am unable to make some UI level enhancements w.r.t. padding, alignment etc.,

This is the Official Spec of Material Design for Drawer-

[image: According to the spec of Material Design]

In the above image, the **UNIT** of measurement is **dp**.

But, in my React Native code, I see there is no such units mentioned. Considering it is "react native" I am confused whether it is **px** or **dp**.

I even went over the Official Docs of [React Native for Style](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html) component. I don't see a mention anywhere.

My Code looks like-

```
const styles = {
    touchable: {
        paddingHorizontal: 16,
        marginVertical: 8,
        height: 48
    },
    item: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    icon: {
        position: 'relative',
    },
    value: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingLeft: 34,
        top: 2
    },
    label: {
        top: 2
    }
},
```

Please can you tell me, if this is pixels or dp? And also, is `1px = 1dp`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I share your confusion somewhat, not being able to actively inspect with a developer console as we are used to in the browser.

I am not familiar with the 'dp' unit, but from what I gather `width: 1` renders differently on each device depending on the pixel density of the screen (see link). The information in the react-native docs say that `1` would render thicker on screens with high pixel density. Which then sounds logical as you have more precision on high density screens than you would have on low density screens and react-native aims at being universal so it would not assume high dpi.

It is my understanding that you can use the below linked PixelRatio API to calculate sizes for detail elements (think borders, icons, etc), that way you can dynamically adjust the rendered size according to the device's screen density.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html#content

Comment: That's quite a great info. Btw, "dp" means - Density-independent Pixel. More infomation -http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html .. To develop native android apps, we use this in xml's to set layouts.

Comment: Coming back to my question,  **height: 48** would mean 40px(or maybe the pixel ratio) right? And its not 40dp right?

Comment: @bozzmob I am glad you found the information interesting, though not exactly what you were looking for. I am not sure about the exact ratio between height: 48 and 40px though. There, like you say, seems to be some ratio calculation happening.

Comment: Thanks for providing the pointers to start exploring though :)

Comment: This answer is misleading and providing inaccurate information. See Nick's answer.

Answer (score 112):

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width.html):

> All dimensions in React Native are unitless, and represent
>   density-independent pixels. Setting dimensions this way is common for components that should always render at exactly the same size, regardless of screen dimensions.

So yes, units in React Native are in `dp`. If you want to convert them to pixels, use `PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize()`

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.  The currently accepted one makes it sound like units are pixels, but most other top google hits disagree with this and clarify they are dp on android and "logical pixels" on ios (a term I'm still trying to figure out, but which I believe may mean "points")

Answer (score 4):

It is the **pixel ratio** that you have to consider. pixel represents an absolute value. pixel ratio is a relative value. to make app screen and components responsive you have to use pixel ratio.

i have been using in multiple apps already. and i think that is how you have to do it. hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. I consider your answer after the analysis I am currently doing. I agree, to get responsive UI, we need pixel ratio.

Answer (score 3):

From what I know, the javascript styling that we use in react js or react native uses pixels. Pixel ratio is only needed to support different size of mobile device screens.

Comment: Thanks. Ok. Will look into it more on how to support different screen sizes. Responsiveness is the prime thing when it comes to app as well.