# React Native png image is pixelated and not hd

Tags: android, image, react-native, png, jsx

I'm trying to display a png icon in my React Native app, on Android for now, using the below code

```
<Image
  style={styles.wtrhIcon}
  source={{uri: "clearmoon"}}/>
```

and the style for it

```
wtrhIcon: {
width: 96,
height: 96,
}
```

This is how it's being rendered

[image]

The big moon seems to be pixelated and doesn't show in hd. The actual png image is 96x96, the exact width and height defined in the style for it.

I have all the png images in android/app/src/main/res/(drawable, drawable-xhdpi, mipmap-hdpi, mipmap-mdpi, mipamp-xhdpi, mipmap-xxhdpi) and i experience the same issue no matter which 96x96 image i chose.

The smaller icons at the bottom seem to be displayed in hd form, i'm guessing because the size is a lot smaller.

So my question is, why is the big image pixelated when the witdh and height defined for it are the same as the actual png image?

Comment: Is the actual PNG blurry?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The actual png image is 96x96,

That's 96 x 96 *pixels*.

> the exact width and height defined in the style for it.

That's 96 x 96 *size units*. These units can be a lot larger than an actual physical screen pixel (in this case 4 times as large) and depend on the pixel density of the screen. See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493372/what-is-the-default-unit-of-style-in-react-native) for more information.

If you measure the actual size of the moon in that image, it's around 375 x 375 pixels. It's being scaled up by a factor of 4 so it looks blurry. You just need to use larger images.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense to me. I tried different png images and looks like I just need larger ones as you said. Will mark as correct answer. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

The germane way which i follow is :

It seems you are using the large image and trying to use it as a small image, what should be done is:

add `resizeMode: 'contain' and flex: 1` in image style object.

> The resizeMode: 'contain' helps in Scale the image uniformly (maintain
>   the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height)
>   of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension
>   of the view (minus padding).

Cheers :)