# React Native - IOS font Size / Dimension issue with IPad

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm implementing very simple layout using React Native StyleSheet mechanism using fontSize, width & height.

Expectation: Layout should look the same in different screen sizes and resolutions.

Actual: IPad looks quite different - objects are out of screen.

Is my assumption correct? Why is that happening?

Android - Huewai (5.5") - Good
[image]

Android - nexus 7 - Good Enough
[image]

IOS - Iphone 7 - Good
[image]

IPad - Bad!
[Objects are out of screen - will upload later]

Code:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.flatten({
    timeContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    time: {
        marginTop: 50,
        fontSize: 50,
    },
    secondary: {
        color: "#757575",
        fontSize: 22,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    container: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    button: {
        container: {
            width: 170,
            height: 170,
            borderRadius: 100,
            marginTop:30,
        },
        text: {
            fontSize: 50,
        }
    }
});

class MyScreen extends Component {
render() {
        ...

        return (
            <View>
                <AppBar/>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.timeContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.time}>{time}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.secondary}>{date}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                        <Button key={1} raised primary={primary} accent={accent} style={styles.button} text={text} onPress={this.handleClockInOut} />

                    </View>
                    {/*<Text>Location</Text>*/}
                </View>
                <ModalRoot />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a summary of my investigation:

**Problem:**
React Native style [uses DIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493372/what-is-the-default-unit-of-style-in-react-native) (AKA DP) units.

The differences between the different devices is caused since there are different DIP (Density-independent Pixels) resolutions per device.

See List of devices DIP [here](https://material.io/devices/).

**Solution:**
I found [this article from Soluto](https://blog.solutotlv.com/size-matters/) describes best the solutions available.
I used the following code taken from [react-native-viewport-units](https://github.com/jmstout/react-native-viewport-units)

*viewport-units.js*

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native')
  , Dimensions = React.Dimensions
  , {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');

var units = {
  vw: width/100
, vh: height/100
};

units.vmin = Math.min(units.vw, units.vh);
units.vmax = Math.max(units.vw, units.vh);

module.exports = units;
```

*Usage example:*

```
import {vw, vh} from "../path/to/viewport-units";

const styles = StyleSheet.flatten({
    time: {
        fontSize: 13 * vw,
    },
    secondary: {
        color: "#757575",
        fontSize: 6 * vw,
    },
    container: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        marginTop: 5 * vh,
        marginLeft: 10 * vw,
        marginRight: 10 * vw,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    button: {
        container: {
            width: 38 * vw,
            height: 38 * vw,
            borderRadius: 19 * vw,
            marginTop: 5 * vh,
        },
        text: {
            fontSize: 11 * vw,
        }
    }
});
```

Hope that help!

Answer (score 1):

Few things to help you:

1. **For texts**:  To get exact same fontsize .. make sure that the fonts you use in both the platform are same. We saw different font sizes in android and ios but eventually found out that default fonts are itself different.. hence they look different.
2. **Views** : For views and layout make sure you always use flex.And with flex you could attain everything just like you would do for a responsive webapp. Specifying anything in pixels would give you weird results.
   This is because different screens will have different DPI. Hence number of pixels per inch will vary. Although react native tries a lot to help you there with unitless dimensions .. but In practice I have found it to be not very accurate.

And regarding your example:

I gave it a shot :

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Text,
  Button,
  View
} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.flatten({
  timeContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 40
  },
  time: {
    fontSize: 50
  },
  secondary: {
    color: "#757575",
    fontSize: 22,
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  button: {
    container: {
      width: 170,
      height: 170,
      padding: 20,
      borderRadius: 100,
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(89, 21, 226)',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    text: {
      fontSize: 50
    }
  }
});

export default class App extends Component {
  handleClockInOut = () => {
    console.log('clicked');
  }
  render() {
    const time = '22:00'
    const date = '02/01/2034'
    const text = 'TEST'
    return (<View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.timeContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.time}>{time}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.secondary}>{date}</Text>
      </View>
      <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button.container} title={text} onPress={this.handleClockInOut}>
        <Text style={styles.button.text}>{text}</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>);
  }
}
```

I didnt use the Button component that u had in your example .. but I guess the implementation will remain the same.

[image: Ipad pro 5th gen]

[image: Ipad air 2]

[image: Iphone 6]

Also make sure you have enabled Universal on your xcode config 
[image: Xcode config]

Comment: Appreciate the detailed answer !

Comment: How do you explain the different you have in the layout between your first 2 screenshots and your 3rd screenshot? no pixels have been used in the styles...