# Problem with Handling different screen sizes in Android-React native

Tags: android, react-native, user-interface

I'm a bit confused with handling different size of screens for app.

in android there is a unit named `dp` that seems to handle screen size and resolution variation.  i expect when i use this unit instead of pixels, i see same size `component`(like button, ...) in every screen. e.g a button with size `20dp` must look same size in all screens.

in articles i read that React-Native uses `dp` as its main unit as well. so expected the same thing here, but it's not working as i expected. a button with `20dp` aren't looking the same in different screens.

also there are articles in which they show how to handle different screen sizes, although they say RN using `dp` they use some arithmetic logic to scale their components to each screen size.

e.g `const scaleX = Dimension.getWidth() / baseWdith`=> simplified code

the flow is that, we make a UI with an specific base screen and make it look how we want it to be, and then we scale components later in new screens.

my question is that isn't `dp` unit supposed to do the same thing!? why RN didn't handle autoscaling itself? if there is sth named `dp` to manage screen sizes-ratio then why they doing manual scaling?

Comment: because dp doesn't do it unfortunately. check out the pictures from readme of this project: https://github.com/intuit/sdp I don't know what react native does, but based on what you have posted, I think it calculates the scale at runtime for the screens and recalculates the widths and heights of views. Not entirely sure about about react native but android's dp is a lie. The only way you can handle multiple screens with dp is by creating different dimens.xml for different size in res/ but `dp` "sounds" like something the android framework would handle under the hood which it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD**

> thanks for the answer. 1- can u share a snippet code using this for styling 2-it seems for IOS its logical pixels and for android dp. check stackoverflow.com/questions/34493372/… 3-why nothing for scaling width and height at same time. i mean scaling depending on both directions is needed for true scaling

1. Done, I've updated the answer.
2. Pixels are used inside styles, but you can recalculate it for example like that:

   ```
   style={{ borderWidth: 1 / PixelRatio.get() }}
   ```

   Also, you can write your own scaling functions with `PixelRatio` approach
3. All is working fine

   ```
   imageContainer: ViewStyle = {
       height: scaleHeight(63),
       width: scaleWidth(63),
       borderRadius: scaleWidth(63 / 2),
       backgroundColor: R.color.white,
       alignItems: 'center',
       justifyContent: 'center',
   };
   ```

**Original**

> my question is that isn't dp unit supposed to do the same thing!? why RN didn't handle autoscaling itself? if there is sth named dp to manage screen sizes-ratio then why they doing manual scaling?

1) In RN it is just pixels
2) Can't say
3) You can use percentages, but it is not a good solution for pixel-perfect design

**How is it working in my project**

This script is used in production and all is fine;

For scaling sizes, I use 'scaleWidth' and 'scaleHeight'

For scaling distances, e.g distance between status bar and some content, I use 'scaleY'

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

const IPHONE6_SCREEN_WIDTH = 375;
const IPHONE6_SCREEN_HEIGHT = 667;

export const isTablet = DeviceInfo.getDeviceType() !== 'Handset';

export const scaleWidth = (width: number) => {
    if (isTablet) {
        return width;
    }
    return Dimensions.get('screen').width / IPHONE6_SCREEN_WIDTH * width;
};

export const scaleHeight = (height: number) => {
    if (isTablet) {
        return height;
    }
    return Dimensions.get('screen').width / IPHONE6_SCREEN_WIDTH * height;
};

export const scaleX = scaleWidth;

export const scaleY = (height: number) =>
Dimensions.get('screen').height / IPHONE6_SCREEN_HEIGHT * height;

export const scaleFont = scaleWidth;
```

Example:

```
textStyle: TextStyle = {
    fontFamily: R.font.montserratBold,
    fontSize: scaleFont(14),
    lineHeight: scaleHeight(18),
    letterSpacing: scaleWidth(1.75),
    color: R.color.white,
};

smallButtonStyle: ViewStyle = {
    ...this.buttonStyle,
    height: scaleHeight(36),
};

smallTextStyle: TextStyle = {
    ...this.textStyle,
    fontSize: scaleFont(12),
    lineHeight: scaleHeight(15),
    letterSpacing: 0,
    marginHorizontal: scaleWidth(10),
};
```

As I said before, I use scaleY for vertical distances on the screen.
Example:

```
render() {
    const { loginRequestState } = this.props;

    return (
        <HideKeyboardView>
            <KeyboardAwareScrollView
                style={styles.mainContentView()}
                contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior={'never'}
                enableOnAndroid
                contentInset={{ bottom: R.constant.botNavBarPlaceholderHeight }}
            >
                <LinkedText
                    text={R.string.signUp.title}
                    onPress={this.goToSignUp}
                    insets={{ top: scaleY(23) }}
                    alignToEnd
                />
                <Title
                    text={R.string.signIn.title}
                    insets={{ top: scaleY(36) }}
                />
                <SignInButton
                    onPress={this.handleMyElevation}
                    icon={R.image.icon.myElevationLogo}
                    insets={{ top: scaleHeight(30) }}
                    signInVariant={'myElevation'}
                />
                <SeparatorWithText
                    insets={{ top: scaleY(40) }}
                    text={R.string.global.or}
                />
                {this.renderForm()}
            </KeyboardAwareScrollView>

            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <FlexView />
                <BotNavPlaceholder
                    toScreen={'signUp'}
                    onPress={this.goToSignUp}
                />
            </SafeAreaView>
            <TransparentLoadingView
                isVisible={loginRequestState === 'progress'}
            />
        </HideKeyboardView>
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. 1- can u share a snippet code using this for styling 2-it seems for IOS its logical pixels and for android `dp`. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493372/what-is-the-default-unit-of-style-in-react-native 3-why nothing for scaling width and height at same time. i mean scaling depending on both directions is needed for true scaling

Comment: @no_fate If you can, please take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61875092/react-native-app-with-same-code-but-different-result-for-vertical-margins-in-ios?noredirect=1#comment109455426_61875092, if you can, please take a look.

Answer (score 3):

In RN we are not using dp as the unit of scaling. We have to do our own logic to manage different screen sizes. I created my own scaling mechanism with percentage scaling.
below is the common function for calculating the size for different screens

```
 import { Dimensions, PixelRatio } from 'react-native';
const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const widthDP = widthPercent => {
    // Convert string input to decimal number
    const elemWidth = parseFloat(widthPercent);
    return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(screenWidth * elemWidth / 100);
};
const heightDP = heightPercent => {
    // Convert string input to decimal number
    const elemHeight = parseFloat(heightPercent);
    return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(screenHeight * elemHeight / 100);
};
```

You can use these functions as below in any of your screens

```
  const style = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: 2,
        width: widthDP('69.60%'),
        height: heightDP('100%),
    },
    textStyle: {
        textAlign: "center",
        fontSize: widthDP('3.70%'),
        color: '#000000',
    },
})
```

You can use below sample table for dp to percentage conversion

```
 HEIGHT:

5:heightDP('0.80%'),
7:heightDP('1.05%'),
8:heightDP('1.2%')
9:heightDP('1.35%'),
10: heightDP('1.5%'),
11:heightDP('1.60%'),
12:heightDP('1.8%'),
14:heightDP('2.12%'),
15:heightDP('2.25%'),
17:heightDP('2.50%'),
18:heightDP('2.65%'),
19:heightDP('2.80%'),
20: heightDP('2.95%') //
22:heightDP('3.25%'),
24:heightDP('3.5%'),,
25:heightDP('3.66%'),
29:heightDP('4.27%'),
30:heightDP('4.4%'),
31:heightDP('4.58%')
33:heightDP('4.25%'),
35:heightDP('5.15%')
36: heightDP('5.30%')//
39:heightDP('5.75%'),
40:heightDP('5.9%'),
42:heightDP('6.2%'),
48:heightDP('7%'),
50:heightDP('7.35%'),
52:heightDP('7.62%')//
55:heightDP('8.10%'),
64:heightDP('9.40%'),
65:heightDP('9.52%'),
66:heightDP('9.66%'),
67:heightDP('9.80%')
71.6:heightDP('10.50%')
72:heightDP('10.55%')//
76:heightDP('11.15%'),
83:heightDP('12.20%')//
90:heightDP('13.19%'),
91:heightDP('13.35%'),
105:heightDP('15.36%')
109:heightDP('16.00%'),
123:heightDP('18%')
136.7:heightDP('20%')
140:heightDP('20.50%')//
174:heightDP('25.5%'),
190:heightDP('27.88%'),
194:heightDP('28.42%'),
209:heightDP('30.59%')
222:heightDP('32.50%')
224:heightDP('32.80%')//
230:heightDP('33.70%'),
246:heightDP('36%'),
265:heightDP('38.8%'),

328heightDP('48%')
334:heightDP('49%')//
341:heightDP('50%')//
344:heightDP('50.40%')
348:heightDP('51%')
355:heightDP('52%')
409:heightDP('60%'),
423:heightDP('62%')
434:heightDP('63.55%'),


WIDTH:


5:widthDP('1.25%'),
7:widthDP('1.80%')v
8:widthDP('1.99%'),
9:widthDP('2.2%'),
10:widthDP('2.5%'),
12:widthDP('3.0%'),
13:widthDP('3.2%'),
14:widthDP('3.5%'),
15:widthDP('3.70%'), 
16:widthDP('3.90%')//
17:widthDP('4.20%'),
18:widthDP('4%'),
18:widthDP('4.4%'),
20:widthDP('4.83%'),
22:widthDP('5.4%'),
24:widthDP('5.8%'),
26:widthDP('6.40%'),
29:widthDP('7.1%'),
30:widthDP('7.30%'),    
39:widthDP('9.50%'),
40:widthDP('9.80%')
44:widthDP('10.70%'),
45:widthDP('11.00%'),
48:widthDP('11.70%')//
60:widthDP('14.50%')
64:widthDP('15.65%'),
68.5:widthDP('16.7%')
70:widthDP('17.2%')

72:widthDP('17.55%')

75:widthDP('18.30%')
76:widthDP('18.65%')
80: widthDP('22%')
273:widthDP('66.40%'),
286:widthDP('69.60%'),
315:widthDP('76.70%'),
335:widthDP('81.5%'),

WidthDP(1)= 4.190476190476191

HeightDP(1)= 6.857142857142857
```

Comment: I'm not sure why your answer with `roundToNearestPixel` is not marked as correct answer. That solution is the only one that worked for me, at least on Android.