# What is ViewStyle and why we have array in ViewStyle in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm learning TypeScript but today i see a few lines of code like this :

```
  const ROOT: ViewStyle = {
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: color.primary,
  borderRadius: 8,
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  marginHorizontal: spacing[2],
  marginTop: spacing[2],
  paddingHorizontal: spacing[4],
  height: "100%",
}
```

****First of all**, What is ViewStyle??**

I searched google for this but feel like it not have documentation for this, the offical document for this only have `stye` for `View` component, so what is **ViewStyle**, and **TextStyle** also?

And i don't understand why they don't use `marginHorizontal: 2` instead of `marginHorizontal: spacing[2]`, spacing[2] to create space?? But why use that when we can directly choose number for `marginHorizontal` and why we have array in here??

Please help, thank you a lots

Answer (score 3):

To answer 1st question. View in react-native represents kind of div element in  web. And Text is to add text in the View. [ViewStyle](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props) is different from that of [TextStyle](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props) as you will see in the Docs. Not all of Viewstyles are applicable to Text component. Hence separate interface for both.

2ndly React-Native allows only number and percentage in the Style as it calculates the style according to the device pixel ratio. Not an expert here. But you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493372/what-is-the-default-unit-of-style-in-react-native), Also spacing is a fuction of material ui library hence not used by default.

The array in style helps you to add style multiple style to a component without using unnecessary spread operators. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117640/react-native-how-to-combine-external-and-inline-styles)